# How to replace all elements of an ArrayList with another ArrayList which is of different size?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

Given two sorted integer arrays A and B, merge B into A as one sorted array.

> Note: You have to modify the array A to contain the merge of A and B.
>   Do not output anything in your code. TIP: C users, please malloc the
>   result into a new array and return the result.

If the number of elements initialized in A and B are  m  and  n  respectively, the resulting size of array A after your code is executed should be  m + n

Example :

```
Input : 
         A : [1 5 8]
         B : [6 9]

Modified A : [1 5 6 8 9]
```

My Solution:

```
public class Solution {
    public void merge(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {

        int i=0,j=0;
        ArrayList<Integer> al= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(i<a.size() && j<b.size()){
            if(a.get(i)<b.get(j)){
            al.add(a.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        else{
            al.add(b.get(j));
            j++;
        }
    }

    while(i<a.size()){
        al.add(a.get(i));
        i++;
    }

    while(j<b.size()){
        al.add(b.get(j));
        j++;
    }
}
```

I created a 3rd ArrayList where I merged all elements of both 1st and 2nd ArrayLists. Now I have to copy all the elements of 3rd ArrayList into 1st one.
I'm stuck now. Because, when I resized it by using

```
public static void ensureSize(ArrayList<Integer> list, int size){
    list.ensureCapacity(size);
    while(list.size()<size){
        list.add(null);
    }
}

ensureSize(a,al.size());
for(int k=0;k<al.size();k++){
     a.set(k,al.get(k));
}
```

It's giving me ArrayIndexOutOfBound error. I tried `Collections.copy(a,al)`, it too didn't work.

Comment: Did you notice that the assignment is talking about `arrays`, but your code is using `ArrayList`?

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly what's wrong, and exactly where in the code the problem is. Read the exception's description in the JavaDoc, and step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: @Kayamanpublic 
** class Solution {
public void merge(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
}
}
** This will be provided in the editor.

Comment: Since this question looks a lot like homework, I will not give the answer, just a pointer to try to help out. In Java, a Collection has no "fixed size", but rather will check its limit on operations, and adjust. If you create an response ArrayList, you can just cicle trough each array, check if the List already contains the watched Object, and insert if needed.

Comment: and please only post well-formatted code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the two given arrays are already sorted

> Input : A : [1 5 8] B : [6 9]
>
> Modified A : [1 5 6 8 9]

you could do something like this: **Option: 1**

```
public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {

    int[] answer = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < a.length && j < b.length)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[j])       
            answer[k++] = a[i++];

        else        
            answer[k++] = b[j++];               
    }

    while (i < a.length)  
        answer[k++] = a[i++];


    while (j < b.length)    
        answer[k++] = b[j++];

    return answer;
}
```

**Note:** I have used arrays rather than ArrayList as I think that is what the question is asking for. Also it is really helpful to understand the [concept of merging sorted arrays](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Merge/Sorted_arrays), this link will help.

Another option, if you want to be really *snazzy*: **Option: 2**

```
public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {

    int[] answer = new int[a.length + b.length]
    int i = a.length - 1, j = b.length - 1, k = answer.length;

    while (k > 0)
        answer[--k] = 
            (j < 0 || (i >= 0 && a[i] >= b[j])) ? a[i--] : b[j--];
}
```

But if you really wanted to use `Lists` then I would do something like this: **Option: 3**

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> merge(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    int size = Math.max(a.size(), b.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i < a.size()) result.add(a.get(i));
        if (i < b.size()) result.add(b.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

If lists really are the only option I probably wouldn't even use my own algorithm, you could quite simply use built in functions such: **Option: 4**

```
List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>();
all.addAll(list1);
all.addAll(list2);

Collections.sort(all);
```

This last algorithm works for arrays which aren't initially in sorted order, which I don't think you're looking for but it is an option.

How to execute *Option: 3*:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1,5,7,9);
    List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(4,3,11);
    System.out.println(merge(l1,l2));
}
```

From what I gather you also want to merge the new `ArrayList` with the first `ArrayList` and remove any duplicates, I would do something like this:

```
for (Object x : two){
   if (!one.contains(x))
      one.add(x);
}
```

This has [already been answered on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520046/how-to-merge-two-arraylists-without-duplicates), check it out

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Option 1 is completely a simplest approach however, I'm allowed to use only List. Option 3 is helpful. And I'd be glad if you could tell me what I have to do after my code snippet 1.

Comment: I have changed Option 3 a little, maybe this helps @BhaskarSantoshK and I have added how you would execute it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'd like to mention something which needs attention is that, here in the question, you're allowed to use an extra memory however at the end, the result will be compared only with the first list given as argument. So, could you please tell me how can I copy my list al into a ? (a and al are different in size)

Comment: A comment made above was like this:
Since this question looks a lot like homework, I will not give the answer, just a pointer to try to help out. In Java, a Collection has no "fixed size", but rather will check its limit on operations, and adjust. If you create an response ArrayList, you can just cicle trough each array, check if the List already contains the watched Object, and insert if needed

This.. I would like to understand

Comment: `for (Object x : two){
   if (!one.contains(x))
      one.add(x);
}` 

This will merge the arrays, but the resulting array might not be in a sorted order..

Comment: Have a play with it @BhaskarSantoshK the only way to learn is to do

Comment: @Fuber Sure.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: done @Fubar. But I really really want to know how to replace an ArrayList with another ArrayList which is of different size.

Comment: [This stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357212/how-to-replace-one-arraylist-to-another-with-different-size-in-java) has exactly what you just asked for @BhaskarSantoshK

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer please add following code to the above solution before return answer;

```
a = new int[answer.length];
a = Arrays.copyOf(answer, answer.length);
```

and change

```
return answer;
```

to

```
return a;
```

Comment: Thanks.. It can easily be done if I am allowed to use arrays. My question is something different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be solved more simply using the following.

- Maintain indexes to both arrays, and read from the smaller element.
- I'd recommend always using for loops rather than while() loops, they're easier to reason with.
- Avoid using variables like i and j, a recipe for typos...

Example

```
int[] a = { 1, 5, 8 };
int[] b = { 6, 9 };

int aPos = 0;
int bPos = 0;
int n = a.length + b.length;

int[] result = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (aPos == a.length) {
        // at end of A, must use B
        result[i] = b[bPos++];
    } else if (bPos == b.length) {
        // at end of B, must use A
        result[i] = a[aPos++];
    } else if (a[aPos] < b[bPos]) {
        result[i] = a[aPos++];
    } else {
        result[i] = b[bPos++];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```